# Splitting Text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split a list of string where it shows the drawing number before the sheet number.

I have tried using formulas like left and trim, and then rewriting them in VBA using the Application.WorksheetFunction.Find command, but I haven't got anywhere.

```
Sub GetIssued()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object


Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

r = 14


fle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fle)


With Sheets("TELECOM")
Range("A14", "I305").ClearContents
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    Cells(r, 9) = objFile.Name
    drwnName = Left(TELECOM.Cells(r, "I"), 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("s", TELECOM.Cells(r, "I")) - 1)
    Cells(rw, "B") = drwnName
    Cells(rw, 9).ClearContents
    rw = rw + 1
Next
End With

End Sub
```

I just want the string before the "s" and then retrieve the data after the "s" and before the "^" in another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous ways of achieving this:

**(1) The string to be extracted is always the same length**

```
splitstr = Left(.Cells(r, "I").Value,8)
```

**(2) Using the Split function**

[This function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) splits a string into an array based on a delimiter

```
splitarr = Split(.Cells(r, "I").Value, "s")
splitstr = splitarr(0) 'would return the first split string
```

**(2) Using the Instr function**

[This function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) determines the position of a substring within a string. This can determine the length of the string you want to extract

```
splitlength = Instr(1, .Cells(r, "I").Value, "s") - 1
splitstr = Left(.Cells(r, "I").Value, splitlength)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Instr() function, that searches for a character inside a string, instead of Find() method that searches for a string in a Range

And put a dot before all your range references inside a “With someSheetReference ...End With” block to have those ranges qualified with that sheet reference

```
With Sheets("TELECOM")
    .Range("A14", "I305").ClearContents
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        .Cells(r, 9) = objFile.Name
        drwnName = Left(.Cells(r, "I").Value, 
Instr(.Cells(r, "I").Value, "s") - 1)
        .Cells(rw, "B") = drwnName
        .Cells(rw, 9).ClearContents
        rw = rw + 1
    Next
End With
```